# Angularjs cannot perform crud operations from accordion

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add a form to a bootstrap accordion and post a text value. Without accordion the form works alright. When i added the form to the accordion i am not able to pass text box value to angularjs controller. Basically i am not able to perform the CRUD operations as i am not able to pass the values. Minimum code related to the issue.

**main.html**

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
<accordion class="accordion" close-others="oneAtATime">
        <accordion-group  ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="status.isOpen[$index]" >
            <accordion-heading>
                {{group.groupTitle}} <i class="fa chevron-icon" ng-class="{'fa-chevron-down': status.isOpen[$index], 'fa-chevron-right': !status.isOpen[$index]}"></i>
            </accordion-heading>
            <div ng-include="group.templateUrl"></div>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
App.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'Parts', function($scope, Parts) {
var original = $scope.parts;

$scope.submit = function() {
if ($scope.parts.a_id == null) {
$scope.createNewPart();
} else {
$scope.updatePart();
}
};
$scope.createNewPart = function() {
Parts.resource1.create($scope.parts);
};
$scope.updatePart = function() {
Parts.resource2.update($scope.parts)
};
$scope.oneAtATime = true;

                $scope.groups = [{
                    groupTitle: "ADD 1",
                    templateUrl: "file1.html"
                }, {
                    groupTitle: "ADD 2",
                    templateUrl: "file2.html"
                }];

                $scope.status = {
                    isOpen: new Array($scope.groups.length)
                };

                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.status.isOpen.length; i++) {
                    $scope.status.isOpen[i] = (i === 0);
                }

} ]);
```

**file1.html**

```
            <div>
            <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
            <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-lable" for="part">Add1</label>

            <input type="text" ng-model="parts.part" id="part" required />

            </div>
            <div class="row">

            <input type="submit" value="{{!parts.id ? 'Add' : 'Update'}}" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">

            </div>
            </form>

//inside table
        <tr ng-repeat="a in availableparts > 
    <td>{{a.id}}</td> 
    <td>{{a.apart}}</td> 
    <td><button type="button" ng-click="editPart(a.id)" >Edit</button> 
    <button type="button" ng-click="deletePart(a.id)">Remove</button> 
    </td> 
    </tr>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please, post whole controller

Comment: Please check edited controller. Also i list all the parts in a table. In that i am getting all part names, but id column is empty. But i get id values in response. its just not showing on table.

Comment: If you want any additional code, please let me know.

Comment: lets make some things clear. 1) I cannot see where in your controller `parts` is assigned to `$scope.parts` 2) `myController` is not the same as declared in template (which is `myCtrl`) 3) `['$scope', 'Parts', function($scope, parts)` should be `['$scope', 'Parts', function($scope, Parts)`. So now I kinda doubt that your app originally worked without accordion

Comment: If you handwrote the posted pieces of code, please copy-paste them directly

Comment: Sorry all copy paste mistake in urgency. I have edited now. Without accordion its working fine.

Comment: It might be happening because of multiple forms with identical name. `<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">` . Since you have accordion groups, I assumed you should have multiple form instances

Comment: Yeah i have 2 forms. but i named them differently and i checked that. no issue over there. i am not able to get id value or pass text box value to controller. As i said above i am getting id values in response its not showing on table. Also i able to pick id value  on click, but cannot pass it to controller.

Comment: Can you post the code where you _able to pick id value on click, but cannot pass it to controller_

Comment: <tr
ng-repeat="a in availableparts >
<td>{{a.id}}</td>
<td>{{a.apart}}</td>
<td><button type="button" ng-click="editPart(a.id)" >Edit</button>
     <button type="button" ng-click="deletePart(a.id)">Remove</button>
</td>
</tr>

Comment: This is a table showing list. here i am getting part names. but it doesnt print id values. but i can get id value on console log on edit/delete click. but cannot pass it to controller. I have added above also

Comment: please someone help me

Comment: To be honest, at this point it is difficult to help you without plunker with minimal code. Or I may try to help you over teamviewer

Comment: Yes you can take team viewer. I will leave my email id here when you are here and delete it soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, you need to set `$scope.parts` to empty object `{}`, so when you access `$scope.parts.id` you will have `null`, instead of error saying `id` of `undefined`